# How can I correctly add referenced hashes to a data structure without overwriting earlier values?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I'm using the Perl [`JSON`](http://metacpan.org/module/JSON) module to convert a Perl hash to a JSON string.  I can't figure out how to add new hashes to the array of hashes while maintaining the keys and values assigned previously.

I am trying to create the following JSON:

```
{
  "key1":"value1",
  "key2":"value2",
  "arrayOfHash":[
    {
      "key1-1":"value1-1",
      "key1-2":"value1-2"
    },
    {
      "key2-1":"value2-1",
      "key2-2":"value2-2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the code:

```
use JSON; # imports encode_json, decode_json, to_json and from_json.

$json{key1}   = "value1";
$json{key2}   = "value2";

%hash             = ();
$hash{'key1-1'}   = "value1-1";
$hash{'key1-2'}   = "value1-2";
push(@{ $json{arrayOfHash} }, \%hash);

%hash             = ();
$hash{'key2-1'}   = "value2-1";
$hash{'key2-2'}   = "value2-2";
push(@{ $json{arrayOfHash} }, \%hash);

$json = encode_json(\%json);
```

What I'm getting is:

```
{
  "key1":"value1",
  "key2":"value2",
  "arrayOfHash":[
    {
      "key2-1":"value2-1",
      "key2-2":"value2-2"
    },
    {
      "key2-1":"value2-1",
      "key2-2":"value2-2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You've written very strange Perl code. If you can explain your situation properly then I'm sure we could help you better. Why do you want to build a Perl data structure and reencode it as JavaScript?

Comment: JSON does not automatically mean JavaScript. The end product will transfer data between perl and PHP.  Also if perl is used in an ajax call then perl (most likely) would need to convert to JSON before returning data.

Comment: ***JSON*** means JavaScript data -- *JavaScript Object Notation*. Perl is spelled ***Perl***. AJAX is spelled ***AJAX***. The format of the data returned depends entirely on the API

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're taking a reference to a hash and then changing the hash. The reference does not create a copy of the hash, but rather, still points at the same data structure. (See [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) and [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) for more information about creating and using references in Perl.)

Instead, you need to:

```
push(@{ $json{arrayOfHash} }, {%hash});
```

Or:

```
push(@{ $json{arrayOfHash} }, {
    'key1-1' => 'value1-1', 
    'key1-2' => 'value1-2',
});
```

You should also `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of every single Perl file you write.

Comment: The 1st one works great.  Ultra simple fix to the issue.

Comment: You can usually achieve a similar result with `my` and lexically scoping a hash to the current iteration. (If you are looping,  which you often are)

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `%hash` refers to the same hash each time - when you say

```
%hash = ();
```

You aren't creating a new hash, you're just emptying out that hash. Here are two ways to do what you want. First, you can use explicit hash references from the start:

```
use JSON; # imports encode_json, decode_json, to_json and from_json.

$json{key1}   = "value1";
$json{key2}   = "value2";

$hash               = {};
$hash->{'key1-1'}   = "value1-1";
$hash->{'key1-2'}   = "value1-2";
push(@{ $json{arrayOfHash} }, $hash);

$hash               = {};
$hash->{'key2-1'}   = "value2-1";
$hash->{'key2-2'}   = "value2-2";
push(@{ $json{arrayOfHash} }, $hash);

$json = encode_json(\%json);

print $json;
```

Second, since you really seemed to want to avoid references where possible, you can use blocks and `my` declarations to make the two `%hash` things different things:

```
use JSON; # imports encode_json, decode_json, to_json and from_json.

$json{key1}   = "value1";
$json{key2}   = "value2";

{
    my %hash               = ();
    $hash{'key1-1'}   = "value1-1";
    $hash{'key1-2'}   = "value1-2";
    push(@{ $json{arrayOfHash} }, \%hash);
}

{
    my %hash               = ();
    $hash{'key2-1'}   = "value2-1";
    $hash{'key2-2'}   = "value2-2";
    push(@{ $json{arrayOfHash} }, \%hash);
}

$json = encode_json(\%json);

print $json;
```

Either of these approaches will do what you want.